# Probabilty of marbles with and without replacement

Tags: probability

Given an urn that contains exactly 50 blue marbles, 40 green marbles, and 10 red marbles, calculate the following probabilities

a) the probability of drawing a marble that is not blue and, after replacing it, a marble that is not green, and, without replacing it, a marble that is not red.

b) the probability of drawing a marble that is blue and, without replacing it, a marble that is not green and, without replacing it, a marble that is not red.

c) the probability of drawing a marble that is not blue and, without replacing it, a marble that is not green and, without replacing it, a marble that is not red.

Im having trouble figuring out the last part of part a), b), and the second and third parts of c). For a) I have 1/2 * 6/10 * ____ but for the blank im not sure how to do the probability of the marble not being red after all the non-replacements. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a)$ $$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{10}{100}\frac{(40+50)}{99} + \frac{50}{100}\frac{(40+49)}{99}\right]$$

$(b)$ $$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{10}{99}\frac{(40+49)}{98} + \frac{49}{99}\frac{(40+48)}{98}\right]$$

$(c)$ $$\frac{1}{10}\left[\frac{9}{99}\frac{(40+50)}{98} + \frac{50}{99}\frac{(40+49)}{98}\right] + \frac{4}{10}\left[\frac{10}{99}\frac{(39+50)}{98} + \frac{50}{99}\frac{(39+49)}{98}\right]$$

---

Ask if you want me to explain some part.

Comment: the way you formatted it allowed me to better picture what the first answer was explaining. Very appreciated. It makes complete sense now! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @KrakenNeedsHelp np, You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

a) the trick here, is at the time you pull the second marble, is it red?  Maybe it is, and maybe it isn't.  Calculate the probability that its, and the consequence.  then the probability that it is not.

(not blue)(red)(not red) + (not blue)(blue)(not red)

(50/100)(10/100)(90/99) + (50/100)(50/100)(89/99)

b)

(blue)(blue)(not red) + (blue)(red)(not red)

c)

(green)(blue)(not red) + (red)(blue)(not red) + (green)(red)(not red)+(red)(red)(not red)

Comment: That explanation makes sense. Thank you. I was having trouble wrapping my head around how to do that